# Android sprite sizes?

Tags: android

When creating an android game for example space invaders. How big would the sprites have to be? The Enemy ships and player ship and boss ships. So they fit on the android phone and is playable. I'm confused between resolution and this.

Thanks.

Comment: "How big would the sprites have to be?" - how big do you *want* them to be? (you could use low res pictures and scale those up without filtering to get a pixelated effect)

Comment: I am confused on this part, I don't know what size the sprites should be to look decent on an android phone. So if enemy sprites, characters are 64x64. Bullets and coins are 16x16. And if the game is played landscape how big should the canvas be so everything fits and looks right?

Comment: This partially depends on your development environment.  Is this native Android development?

Comment: This is largely a matter of style and taste. To check it out, try taking a paint program and setting up a new image with the resolution of a common Android device. Paste some placeholder sprites from a free/creative commons asset site into this image, to get an idea of how they look relative to the screen size. Zoom the image so it's the right physical size on screen to judge how easy they'll be to touch. Repeat with different sized sprites (and at least a few different target phone specs, since there's a lot of variety here) to figure out what set of sizes best serves your game's goals.